# How can I confirm the delay on a digital ticket?

Tags: trains

When missing connections in case of train delays, it is recommended to have the delay confirmed on the first ticket (for example, [*the passenger must present a confirmation of this delay, that he received from the delayed operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_on_Journey_Continuation)).  Classically this happened by the conductor stamping or signing the ticket, but these days many travellers have paperless tickets, such as tickets in smartphone apps or as Aztec codes in their smartphone.  How can delays be confirmed/proven in this case?

Comment: Some train operator apps allow you to get a proof of delay, though I never used any so I’m not quite sure how those work. But more generally, one would expect train managers to be able to check previous trains delays with their own smartphones or other mobile terminals nowadays.

Comment: @jcaron maybe in the same country, but internationally probably not; and those systems aren't always working as they should (should I add a [tag:tagskryt] tag already? ;-)

Comment: Even internationally I would expect them to be able to look up quite a few things. You can also show them the delay in the app you surely have for those trains :-) But otherwise you can always ask the conductor of the delayed train, I’m pretty sure they have a way to issue some proof of delay even if you don’t have a printed ticket. Alternatively you can ask at the destination station, but nowadays this often involves a loooooong wait.

Comment: I have not bothered getting confirmation of delays for a long time. Conductors can always look up if a train was delayed and confirm your story.

Answer (score 2):

That depends a lot on the specific train operator. Chances are, that if they have enough technology to issue an electronic ticket, they have enough technology to verify & track delays.

In Germany, for example, this is completely automatic. They track your itinerary life and if you are going to miss a connection, they will sent you a notification and alternative options up front so you can decide what to do. The app with your ticket will update status life and give you an estimate whether you will make your next connection or not.